# Sort a list of tasks by date value

Tags: list, sort

I'm trying to sort a list of tasks by their due date in ascending order. I've looked in a couple of forums and none are what I exactly need. I'm sure this should be relatively easy but haven't found the way.

```
list <task> Tareas_abiertas  = [SELECT Id from Task where OwnerId =:usuario.id AND status='Open'];
```

My query is simple I just need to order it depending on due date. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
list <task> Tareas_abiertas  = [SELECT Id from Task where OwnerId =:usuario.id AND status='Open' Order By ActivityDate];
```

And from this [Salesforce help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232236&type=1) you can see that the API name of Due Date is ActivityDate.

Also as suggested by @IllusiveBrian, here is the documentation on SOQL Order By - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm#

Comment: Here's the documentation on SOQL ordering, as well - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm#

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple. Thank you very much!